# In odoo10 when I click send by email button it takes saleperson name in recipients

Tags: odoo-10

When I click send by email button in quotation or Sales Order it's open one wizard that contain recipients field in that I need saleperson name as recipients.

[image]

Comment: Hi, You can add picture please.

Answer (score 0):

First Goto Settings --> Technical --> Email --> Templates

Click Template Menu open that form view. In that Select Email Configuration Page after Content Page.
Click Edit on Top of the View. Then set ${object.user_id.id} in cc field